# Creating a Linux executable file for my Java application Jar file

Tags: java, executable, packr

I found that [Packr](https://github.com/libgdx/packr) is the best tool to use for creating an executable file for my Java application on Linux. The executable works perfectly on Linux, but i have a question about this tool:

The tool forces me to embed JRE with the output folder causing big output size for my application. Can i create the executable without embedding JRE with it?

Comment: Java applications can't run without a JRE...unless you want to distribute a JAR and require that everyone that installs your application have the JRE installed, bundling the JRE in your executable is the only other real option.

Comment: There has to be a JRE involved somewhere, and if you're not bundling the JRE then there's no point in not just distributing a jar.

Comment: I am aware of course that JRE is needed to run Java applications, but none of my users had problems downloading and installing JRE manually, so i see no need to bundle a JRE with my application. I just want to have an executable with my application to be user friendly for Linux users, just like an *.exe file in Windows operating system.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java 9 or above you can use [jlink](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/tools-and-command-reference.htm#JSWOR596) to create an image that only contains the required jre modules and therefore will likely give you a smaller distributable. There's a tutorial [here](https://dzone.com/articles/jlink-in-java-9)

Comment: Nice suggestion, but i am still using Java 8.